# React useeffect shows mounting of component in 2 times

Tags: reactjs, components, use-effect

i have a component names "Home" and i have a useEffect inside it which has a console.log("Home component mounted"). I just used a common useEffect hook. But when i initially render the page I getting the console log 2 times instead of showing it in the initial mounting of component. Can anyone tell me whats happening with my code. The code is as follows:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Home = () => {

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("Home component mounted")
  })

 return (
  <div className="container">
    <h1 className="h1">Home Page</h1>
  </div>
 )};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's happening because in your app in strict mode. Go to index.js and comment strict mode tag. You will find a single render.

This happens is an intentional feature of the React.StrictMode. It only happens in development mode and should help to find accidental side effects in the render phase.

Or you can try to use this hook : `useLayoutEffect`

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from "react";

const Home = () => {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("Home component mounted");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1 className="h1">Home Page</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because of React.StrictMode

You don't have to worry- just that StrictMode runs your effect code twice(only during development, don't have to worry about production) to be able to catch bugs and memory leaks among other things

Read more: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYFq3.png)

Answer (score 0):

useEffect() equivalent with componentDidMount() and componentDidUpdate(). This means when rendering your component, useEffect() will be called twice. If you want useEffect() only called one time, you just add the second parameter for it. It will as this.

```
useEffect(()=>{
console.log("Home component mounted")},[])
```

I hope this helpful for you!

Comment: I tried as you said. But eventhough it is shows 2 times. But the first answer seems Okay for me. Thanks for your initiation.

Comment: Either way you should always have a dependency array, even if it's empty. Otherwise your useEffect will fire on every single state change.